# BEMCheckBox don't seem to follow constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

Hi im trying to add a checkbox beside my task text but it wont follow my constraints, constraints set as pic one, but when I compile it shows me like in picture two.
I tried to put them inside a stackView but it made no difference.

[image: How it looks in storyboard]
[image: How it looks when I build]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was setting the tableview.textfield.text = to the task text.

What I wanted to do was to set my customTableViewCells textfield.text = to the task.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
```

and the put the `cell.textFeild.text = myTask`